# SQL exercise - implicit join

Tags: sql, db2

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm a beginner, trying to solve an exercise and can't understand why as result I get nothing but the headers.

I'm using IBM Db2.

Consider 2 tables:

```
CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS: (COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME | SAFETY_SCORE)

CENSUS_DATA: (COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME | PER_CAPITA_INCOME)
```

Exercise:
[Without using an explicit JOIN operator] Find the Per Capita Income of the Community Area which has a Safety Score of 1

my code:

```
SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, PER_CAPITA_INCOME 

FROM CENSUS_DATA 

where COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME IN
            (SELECT  COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS
                WHERE SAFETY_SCORE=1)
```

Thanks a lot to whoever will help me understanding

EDIT:
A little add on based on the first two comments I received, hoping this might be helpful. the safety score shouldn't be an issue, since the following code works properly:

SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS
WHERE SAFETY_SCORE=1

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me. Maybe there is just no row with SAFETY_SCORE=1 in CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS?

Comment: Hello Thorsten, 
I checked in separate queries and I can confirm there is (checked also manually in Excel)

Comment: Are you sure that SAFETY_SCORE is a numeric data type? If it is a string data type that condition won't ever be true, at least in most DBMS. **Disclaimer:** I never used IBM Db2 but I'm assuming that in this case, it would be very similar to the others DBMS.

Comment: Hi David, I just edited my message =) if I run only the second part of the query, the code works properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should qualify all column names in any query that has more than one table reference:

```
SELECT cd.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, cd.PER_CAPITA_INCOME 
FROM CENSUS_DATA cd
WHERE cd.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME IN
            (SELECT cps.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME
             FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS cps
             WHERE cps.SAFETY_SCORE = 1
            );
```

Here are possibilities that I can readily think of to explain why this query would return no rows:

1. Either table has no rows.
2. `CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS` has no rows that match `SAFETY_SCORE = 1`.
3. Any rows with `SAFETY_SCORE = 1` have area names that are not in the census table.
4. `COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME` does not match between the two tables.

You have not provided sample data or a fiddle.  Here are some ideas for debugging:

For the first possibility, run `COUNT(*)` on the two tables.

For the second, just run the subquery to see if it returns any rows.

For the third, run the subquery and manually check to see if the names match in the table.

For the fourth, you have to consider strings that look the same but are different -- often because of hidden characters.

Comment: Hello Gordon, thanks for your reply.
I think the issue must be that in chicago_public_school the result is 'WASHINGTON PARK', while in census is 'Washington Park'. I'm trying to use LCASE but I fear Im mistaking something in the syntax, could you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: @AlessioBaldessarro . . . If that is the only issue then:  `WHERE LCASE(cd.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME) IN  (SELECT LCASE(cps.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME) . . . ` should work.